# Intricate Inequality

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, summation, contest-math

Let $c$ be the smallest positive real number such that for all positive integers $n$ and all positive real numbers $x_1,....,x_n$ , the below inequality holds. Compute $⌈2022c⌉$.

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(n^3+k^3-k^2n)^\frac{3}{2}}{\sqrt {x_1^2+...+x_k^2+x_{k+1}+...+x_n}}≤\sqrt{3}(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i^3(4n-3i+100)}{x_i})+cn^5+100n^4$$

I was practicing Math Open Spring Contest (OMO Spring 2020) question for upcoming Junior Math Olympiad purpose and had found this interesting problem. Question link : https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/1-sJSrnuEFlrZhd4c-qpb_nURbfxqXbrr

I tried solving this problem with random values of $x_i$ and $1≤n≤4$ but ended up with different values of $c$ each time.

Comment: There are solutions on aops

Comment: Incredibly hard: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c487h2055667